Server name validation failed for Java application while connecting to SSL enabled PostgreSQL database in GCP
GCP team enabled SSL in PostgreSQL database and provided the following certificates:

server-ca.pem
client-cert.pem
client-key.pem

The GCP team selected the following option in their UI while enabling SSL: Only allow connections encrypted with SSL/TLS and with valid client certificates.
We are using Spring Boot and trying to connect our Java application to this SSL-enabled PostgreSQL database in GCP. We are converting client-key.pem to .pk8 as the SSL key file needs to be in either PKCS#5 (.p5k) or PKCS#8 (.der) format.
Command to convert to .pk8:
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -nocrypt -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pk8
application.yml:
spring:
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    open-in-view: false
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource: 
    url: jdbc:postgresql://111.1.1.1:5432/DB?sslmode=verify-ca
    username: uname
    password: pswd
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        ssl: true
        sslmode: verify-ca
        sslfactory: org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactory
        sslrootcert: server-ca.pem          
        sslcert: client-cert.pem      
        sslkey: postgresql-key.pk8

After making these changes in application.yml, we are encountering the following errors in GCP logs during deployment:
ERROR 1:
o.postgresql.ssl.PGjdbcHostnameVerifier: Server name validation failed: certificate for host 111.1.1.1 dNSName entries subjectAltName, but none of them match. Assuming server name validation failed
PSQLException:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The hostname 111.1.1.1 could not be verified by hostnameverifier PgjdbcHostnameVerifier.
ERROR 2:
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: The hostname 111.1.1.1 could not be verified by hostnameverifier PgjdbcHostnameVerifier.
We are trying to connect our Spring Boot application to the PostgreSQL database in GCP with SSL enabled but are facing the errors mentioned above.
We want our Java application to connect to the database with SSL enabled successfully.
Please let us know if any changes are required in the application.yml or if there is an issue with the certificates. The error seems related to the certificate, but we are unsure what changes would be required from the GCP team.

Try connection to the host by name (the name included in the server cert), not by IP address.
